# How to override field name attribute in django model form?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I have a model form similar to the one below:

```
class BookSearchForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = Book
       fields = ['publisher', 'authors', 'category'
```

How to override fields **name attribute** in the above model form?

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
class BookSearchForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = Book
       fields = ['publisher', 'authors', 'category'
       widgets = {
           'publisher': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'name': 'pub'}),
           'authors': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'name': 'aut'}),
           'category': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'name': 'cat'}),
       }
```

Comment: Why do you want to override the _name_ attribute? Just set the name to what the form is expecting if you want to write the HTML manually.

Comment: Handle the form manually then

Comment: For example, I want to write the form as `{{ form.publisher }}` in HTML while its name attribute is "pub".

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to change the **name** of a field in the forms, django needs that to collect data for that field if you don't provide [db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#db-column) as the name of the db column. what you can do with the first option, if you want the user to see publisher or some other name, in the models, add a verbose_name and then for the actual name you can declare the field however you want. Your code could look like this

```
pub = models.WhateverField(verbose_name='what i want you to see')
```

now when you do `{{form.pub.label)}}`, '**what i want you to see**' is displayed in the html. Of course, don't forget to add the actual input in you template, `{{form.pub}}`. This way, you don't add anything extra in the form to display a user friendly name. I've posted this as an answer as i ran out of characters for a commment.

Comment: Thank you, but I know the difference between name (in html attr) and verbose name (in django).
I want to change the name attribute. the one that appears as a parameter in the address bar when sending a get request.